# Linking background colour change [css] to background image change [javascript]

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using the following code to change the background image when the page is refreshed

```
function changeImg(imgNumber) {
    var myImages = ["../img/background_tile.png", "../img/background_tile_blue.png", "../img/background_tile_green.png", "../img/background_tile_purple.png"]; 
    var newImgNumber =Math.floor(Math.random()*myImages.length);
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+myImages[newImgNumber]+')';
}
window.onload=changeImg;
```

Now I'm trying to make the CSS `background-color` change to the color of the image so that when the page is refreshed it doesn't flash white before it loads.

Website - http://lauramccartney.co.uk

Edit - I worked it out guys! I used this

```
function changeImg(imgNumber) {
    var myImages = ["../img/background_tile.png", "../img/background_tile_blue.png", "../img/background_tile_green.png", "../img/background_tile_purple.png"]; 
    var myColors = ["#d1261e", "#6167e6", "#3db322", "#a12cbb"];
    var newImgNumber =Math.floor(Math.random()*myImages.length);
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+myImages[newImgNumber]+')';
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = myColors[newImgNumber];
}
window.onload=changeImg;
```

Didn't make much of a difference so I also adjusted the background in the css to an inoffensive grey.

Comment: But... but, why 2 arrays?. Use a single array, instead of maintaining two arrays. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

How about this :

Instead of just storing the `img` path, store it like `color url('url-to-image')`, and use that as the background while calling it.

So your array would look like : `['color1 url(url-1)', 'color2 url(url-2)', ...]` and change the javascript to use `document.body.style.background = array[array-index];`

```
/*Makes background image change when refreshed*/
function changeImg(imgNumber) {
    var myImages = ["red url(../img/background_tile.png)", "blue url(../img/background_tile_blue.png)", "green url(../img/background_tile_green.png)", "orange url(../img/background_tile_purple.png)"]; 
    var newImgNumber =Math.floor(Math.random()*myImages.length);
    document.body.style.background = myImages[newImgNumber];
}
window.onload=changeImg;
```

Comment: I was going to use an associative array but this is a much quicker and easier approach!

Answer (score 1):

It's always better to delegate styling to css classes, like this:

theme.css:

```
.theme-1 {
    background:red url(../img/background_tile.png);
}
.theme-2 {
    background:green url(../img/background_tile_green.png);
}
.theme-3 {
    background:orange url(../img/background_tile_purple.png);
}
```

apply-theme.js:

```
/* Apply random class to body */
function setRandomTheme() {
    var styles = ["theme-1", "theme-2", "theme-3"],
        random = Math.floor(Math.random() * styles.length);
    document.body.className += ' ' + styles[random];
}
```

And if you want to change background instantly, without flash of unstyled content, call `setRandomTheme` right before closing `body` tag:

```
<body>
    <p>La-la-la, some content</p>
    … skipped some code …
    <script type="text/javascript">setRandomTheme();</script>
</body>
```

Or from [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded) event:

just add this to apply-theme.js after setRandomTheme declaration:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    setRandomTheme(); 
});
```